# PHP SQL ignore all characters before "-" like statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select a mssql row however I want to ignore the characters in a certain column before a certain character.

This is the column format:

```
|5555-55555|
```

I want to ignore everything before the dash "-" and only see if my variable $search shows up after. Then that's the row I want. I would prefer if it was an exact match. Is this possible or do I have to create a new column with just the number after the dash?

```
$search = '55555'
$query .= "WHERE '$columnName' LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Answer (score 3):

Will match any *-55555

```
$search = '55555';
$query .= "WHERE '$columnName' LIKE '%-$search'";
```